# How many total NASA astronauts have died?

Tags: nasa, astronauts, death

Including in space, launching, reentering, pre-flight, and in training.

Comment: Do you include by natural causes? By "in training" do you include car wrecks, personal plane crashes, etc? Or do you mean only NASA related deaths? How about plane crashes while on business travel for NASA? After retirement?

Comment: related: [Is the overall mortality rate for being in a spacecraft in space or bound for space about 4%?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14985/12102) and [time trends in astronaut fatality rates?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51428/12102) and [Where does space travel rank in per-passenger-mile safety?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26456/12102)

Comment: Also, how about non-NASA astronauts? Two of the STS-51L crew were payload specialists (McAuliffe and Jarvis), not part of NASA.